# boto3 s3.Object- - expected string or bytes-like object

Tags: python, boto3

I tried searching for a solution to this problem but still couldn't figure out the issue. So, I am trying to check if a key exists in a bucket. My code works perfectly fine if I use the following:

```
s3.Object("bucket_name", "key_name").load()
```

But when I pass the reference variable rather than the actually values, I get an error.

```
bucket = "bucket_name"
key = "key_name"
s3.Object(bucket, key).load()
```

Error: `expected string or bytes-like object`

Edit -  I don't get this issue in python shell. I get it only when I run this through a python module.

Comment: Have you tried b"bucket_name" and b"key_name"?

Comment: Hey,
I figured out my mistake. It was very silly one. There was actually a dangling comma after bucket assignment. Anyway thanks. :)

Comment: Cheers! to dangling comma.